# How to omit the dots, commas and white spaces for a string (needed for checking a palindrome)

Tags: c, c99

My program for checking a palindrome (with use of pointers) must count with few kinds of cases.

Input can be:

1. one symbol/letter (done)
2. a word with upper/lower case letters (done)
3. bunch of symbols; if only symbols, then it is always an palindrome (done)
4. if the input is too large(>80), then it is not a palindrome (I need to use fgets for that, which I managed to get done)
5. combination of letters and symbols, if so, then just count letters (STRUGGLING WITH)
6. a sentence with whites and commas (STRUGGLING WITH)
   -->To get an input, I'm prompted to use only fgets function because of the case 4. I still can't manage to convert the input string to the desired form

e. g.:
input: Madam, I'm Adam
output: palindrome
input: ?a.a!
output: palindrome

I've already managed to create the palindrome function with use of pointers, to convert possible letters in a string to all-lower-case, and to display "palindrome" if the string consists only of symbols.

How could I manage to transform e. g.:

```
char str[80] = "Madam, I'm Adam";
```

into:

`str[80] = "madamimadam";` ?

Comment: You are not allowed to use [isalpha](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha)?

Comment: @P.W not exactly sure about that, we can use some tools but e. g. for upper/lower cases I had to create an original function (which I've done) but thanks for the hint, I will try it with it at least

Answer (score 0):

Simply chew through the whole string and create a new one in a more convenient format. At the same place as you do the case conversion:

```
#include <ctype.h>

void format (char* dst, const char* src)
{
  size_t i=0;

  while(*src != '\0')
  {
    char ch = tolower(*src);
    if(isalpha(ch))
    {
      *dst = ch;
      dst++;
    }
    src++;
  }
}
```

If `isalpha` isn't available for some artificial reason, you can easily create it yourself. Here's a fast, portable look-up table version:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool my_isalpha (char ch)
{
  static const bool ALLOWED[256] =
  {
    ['A'] = true;
    ['B'] = true;
    ['C'] = true;
    ...
  };

  return ALLOWED[ch];
}
```

Naive versions of the same function simply check `if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')`, assuming upper-case only. That's probably ok for a student assignment, but not for production quality code. Since there's no guarantee from the C standard that characters are adjacent in the symbol table. And the look-up table version runs much faster anyway, so there's no reason not to use it in a professional program.

Comment: ("so there's no reason not to use it in a professional program" Except of course if you are programming some 1980s crapitechture 8-bit MCU with very limited flash.)